# FFmpeg command execution

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to file name space allowed in `ffmpeg` command execution time and executing this command in android. i.e
`ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/**folder name/file name**.mp4` any way to handle space allowed?

I m getting error in logcat **No such file or directory error**

Comment: Did you try ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/folder\ name/file name.mp4 ?

Comment: means filename.replace(" ","\ ") it's right?

Comment: Yes. paste it as i typed in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use backspace for negating the effect of space.
Use the below line as it is.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/folder\ name/file name.mp4
```

Comment: getting No such file or directory error when executing command

Comment: if i m executing command in mac working properlay but in android device error no such file or directory problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi you probably solved that already, but for anyone else here, there is simple workaround for that issue.

Just get rid of white spaces

```
String rawFileName = filename;
String filename = filename.replaceAll(" ", ""); 

String rawSource = rootFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + rawFileName;
String source = rootFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename;

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"mv", rawSource, source});
process.

String cmd = "-i " + source + " " + target;
```

and now

```
FFmpeg.getInstance(getBaseContext()).execute(cmd, listener);
```